# Storing special characters with R in csv

Tags: r, csv, unicode, encoding, utf-8

I need a solution for storing special characters like emojis, arabic or chinese characters in a csv. I tried the base `write.csv`, `write.csv2` with the `fileEncoding="UTF-8"` parameter and the readr-function `write_csv` but nothing worked properly. The special characters are shown in R, so I guess there is a solution for storing them.

Example-Code:

```
df <- data.frame("x" = c("ö", "ä"),
                 "y" = c("مضر السامرائي", ""))

write.csv(df, "~/TubeWork/data/test2.csv", fileEncoding = "UTF-8")
```

To check the results I use Excel and it looks as follows:

[image]

Maybe it's a problem of Excel, which can display the results correctly? If yes, how I should check if the characters are displayed correctly?

Is there maybe a solution to convert the characters to unicode and save it as unicode? This would be fine for me as well. But the best solution would be a csv with the special characters displayed.

Thank you in advance!

*Windows 10 64-bit; R 4.2.1; RStudio 2022.12.0+353*

Comment: How are you looking at the output? What is that a screen shot from? That doesn't look like the RStudio table viewer. It just looks like your viewer program doesn't understand unicode. The file itself is probably fine.

Comment: I am pretty sure the output could be correct. When you say "The output looks as follows" you should not look at the data with an application that encodes the data in a way you don't know. Look at the raw bytes in the file, and compare to how the UTF8 characters are defined. [Xah Code](http://xahlee.info/comp/unicode_index.html) is just one example.   In your case, `ä` would be `C3 84`  and the rabbit `F0 9F 90 87`. If you look at the `ä` using Windows codepages, it may look exactly as you illustrate, two meaningless bytes.

Comment: Just tested in Python. In UTF8 encoding `ä, ö`  will display as `Ã¤,Ã¶` in Windows-1252.  So in short, data is only what you make of it. If you don't define that your bytes are UTF-8 text, it becomes meaningless.

Comment: I use Excel to check the output.

Comment: If you're opening this data in Excel, use `readr::write_excel_csv()` to include the necessary BOM that tells Excel that the csv file is UTF-8 encoded.

Answer (score 1):

Update!

If I read the exported csv back in R, all the Emojis are displayed correctly. So as you all wrote, Excel can't diplay the emojis and special character correctly. If I want the special characters displayed in Excel, you should use `readr:write_excel_csv()` (Big Thanks to Ritchie Scramenta for the useful comment).

Once again: Problem solved!

Thank you!